# Cloudcontrol - overriding PHP-FPM settings, server reached pm.max_children

Tags: php, fastcgi, cloudcontrol

I am quite often receiving 'WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (1), consider raising it' in my error logs for my containers on Cloudcontrol, and I am therefore looking for a way to raise this setting.

I have managed to adjust the php.ini and Apache config settings using the buildpack for PHP provided by Cloudcontrol in a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/cloudControl/buildpack-php). However, no luck for the PHP-FPM settings (any changes made in the provided php-fpm.ini are ignored).

I have tried...

- to make changes in the existing php-fpm.ini file, located in the conf/ folder
- creating my own php-fpm.ini, placing it in the php/conf/ folder
- creating my own php-fpm.conf, placing it in the php/conf/ folder, and in the conf/ folder

I am defining the variables as pm = static, and max_children = 3 for the [www] pool and have tried to both include the default variables in my files, as well as just including the variables that I wish to override.

Am I overlooking something, or am I doing this wrong? Is there any better way to deal with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is a deployment that receives traffic scaling the memory per container (will also give you more processes inside the container) and/or scaling to more containers (gives you more processes in total as well and will distribute requests across containers - also gives you higher availability).

Comment: Please mark @vervas' response as the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We added support for overriding the default php-fpm configuration by creating a `php-fpm.ini` file under the `.buildpack/php-fpm/conf/` directory of your project.

Make sure you have a look at the default configuration at https://github.com/cloudControl/buildpack-php/blob/master/conf/php-fpm.ini. For info check the [buildpack-php](https://github.com/cloudControl/buildpack-php#php-buildpack) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You currently can't override the php-fpm settings with this buildpack. You could clone it, change the value in conf/php-fpm.ini and provide it as a [custom buildpack](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Guides/Third-Party%20Buildpacks/Third-Party%20Buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack). In this specific case though, I think it's a bug of the buildpack and the value pm.max_children should be raised. I opened a [issue on github](https://github.com/cloudControl/buildpack-php/issues/10) for you.